# Command line arguments as Ints in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I have a Haskell program which accepts 2 or 3 `Int`s from the command line:

```
-- test.hs

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- fmap (read . head) getArgs
    case args of
        [x,y,a] -> doGeneration x y a
        [x,y]   -> doGeneration x y 10
        _       -> usage
```

However, when I run it with arguments:

```
$ ./test 100 200
divide: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Why?

Comment: For functions with a "polymorphic return type" like `read` it's good practice to specify the type you want to deserialize with [visible TypeApplications](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html?highlight=xtypeapplications#extension-TypeApplications): `read @Int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`getArgs :: IO [String]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs) returns a list of `String`s, by taking the head and then `args` and it will then `read` that item.

You however never specified to what it should read, since you use `args` in a `case … of …` clause with `[x,y,a]` and `[x, y]`, it will try to read it as a *list* of numbers (the type of the number is specified by the `doGeneration` signature. This thus means that you should write it as:

```
$ ./test [100,200]
```

But I think it makes not much sense to do that, you can rewrite the parsing part to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- fmap (map read) getArgs
    case args of
        [x,y,a] -> doGeneration x y a
        [x,y]   -> doGeneration x y 10
        _       -> usage
```

This means that it will `read` every parameter individually, and construct a list with the parsed items, and then we can pattern match on the parsed parts of the program parameters. In that case we thus can still use:

```
$ ./test 100 200
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly and the `map read` part makes much more sense to me than `read . head` which i actually found on SO as accepted answer to similar question.

Comment: "You however never specified to what it should render" is incorrect. the target type is known, and besides the error would talk about "ambiguous type" if it weren't known.

Comment: When in `IO`, it's probably good to get into the habit of using `readIO` instead of `read`, as in `args <- mapM readIO =<< getArgs`. If somebody gives a non-integer argument, you'll find out right away, instead of at some time potentially after a lot of computation has already been done when the wrong argument is forced for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your running code is equivalent to

```
     ....
     case (read "100") of 
         [x,y,a :: Int] -> doGeneration x y a
         [x,y   :: Int] -> doGeneration x y 10
     ....
```

but reading a string `"100"` as a list of `Int`s is impossible, a.k.a. "there's no parse". That's why.

The `Int` comes from `doGeneration`'s signature which you haven't included. But it must be a `Num` since you use `a` and `10` interchangeably.

It's better to use more variables in your `do` block instead of `fmap`, when you learn Haskell. It lessens the cognitive load and lets you see clearer what's going on:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs           -- getArgs :: IO [String]
                              -- args    ::    [String]
    let arg1 = head args      -- arg1    ::     String
        val1 = read arg1
    case val1 of
        [x,y,a] -> doGeneration x y a
        [x,y]   -> doGeneration x y 10
        _       -> usage
```

Comment: I'd have never figured out that `read` expected `[Int]` here. Thank you!